# How to extract multiple array & insert data to database

Tags: php, mysql

How to extract below array & insert 3 data & 2 query

Extract this array & give me 2 row & 3 columns

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => AAAAA
            [1] => BBBBB
        )

    [number] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7878787878
            [1] => 9898989898
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => a@gmail.com
            [1] => b@gmail.com
        )

)
```

We need Below query by foreach loop

```
INSERT INTO `contact_person` SET customer_id='131',cp_name='AAAAA',cp_phone='7878787878',cp_email='a@gmail.com

INSERT INTO `contact_person` SET customer_id='131',cp_name='BBBBB',cp_phone='9898989898',cp_email='b@gmail.com'
```

Comment: you can simply use array key like $array['name'][0] and $array['name'][1]

Comment: And the sql you need is not correct.

Comment: Yes Unex is right, why you insert multiple records for same customer_id?

Comment: 0 and 1 nof fix, this is dynamic like 0,1,2,3

Comment: @MayaShah you are right. But main problem is array formatting. So he need to format his array first or may be need to change his query that fetch record.

Comment: Use foreach http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) like so:

```
$length = count($yourarray['name']);
$queries = new array();
for(i = 0; i < $length; i++) {
    $queries[] = "INSERT INTO `contact_person` SET customer_id='131',
                 cp_name='" . $yourarray['name'][i] . "',
                 cp_phone='" . $yourarray['number'][i] . "',
                 cp_email='" . $yourarray['email'][i] " . "'";
}
```

This will create all the insert queries and put them in an array named `$queries`

> NOTE: This code assumes you always have the same amount of names, numbers and emails

Comment: Thank you Brother

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
      $newArr[$k][$key] =   $v;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArr);
```

Now you can run your insert query in `foreach()` like:

```
foreach($newArr as $key=>$val){
echo "INSERT INTO `contact_person` SET customer_id='131',
                 cp_name='" . $val['name'] . "',
                 cp_phone='" . $val['number'] . "',
                 cp_email='" . $val['email'] " . "'";
echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can summarize the array by using below function.

```
function getSummary($array){
    $summary = [];
    foreach( $array as $col => $data ){
        foreach( $data as $key => $value ){
            $summary[$key][$col] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $summary;
}
```

And once you pass the summarize array to the below function you will get the queries. I assume you need `INSERT` query.

```
function makeQueries($summary){
    foreach( $summary as $data ) {
        echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `contact_person` (customer_id, cp_name, cp_phone, cp_email) VALUES (131, '{$data['name']}', '{$data['number']}', '{$data['email']}');";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

I believe these 2 functions will solve your problems

Answer (score 1):

Make customer_id in your database an autonumber so that it will automatically generate a customer_id on insert.

Also all fields are some text field in db

```
$arr = Array
(
    'name' => Array
        (
            "AAAAA", "BBBBB"
        ),

    'number' => Array
        (
             "7878787878", "9898989898"
        ),

    'email' => Array
        (
            "a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com"
        )
);
$count = count($arr['name']);
$sql = "";
if ($count > 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contact_person` (cp_name, cp_phone, cp_email) VALUES ";
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $sql .= ($i+1==$count) ? "('".$arr['name'][$i]."', '".$arr['number'][$i]."', '".$arr['email'][$i]."'')" : "('".$arr['name'][$i]."', '".$arr['number'][$i]."', '".$arr['email'][$i]."''), ";
    }
}

echo ($sql);
```